# google charts with data from spreadsheet "data table is not defined"

Tags: html, google-visualization, spreadsheet

I'm trying to let a google chart draw with data from a google spreadsheet.
That works very well when I use the code in jsfiddle. But when I paste the code in a html file and try to open it in a browser I always get error messages:
"Data table is not defined"
"Error in query: Request timed out"

I don't unserstand why it is workin in jsfiddle but not in a html file.

Can anyone see a reason for it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<h1>BF Macroeconomic Demand Index</h1>
<h3>Automobile prices, France, all segments</h3>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts

google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawBasic() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fk2tQgEOWPjhY-g7PFzRIEYbso9o2nk4b3a4cJhgGhw/edit?usp=sharing");
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  } else {
  var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    legend: 'bottom',
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '10%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: '',
      viewWindow: {
        max: 2016,
        min: 2027,
      },
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 1.04,
        min: 0.95,
      },
    }
  };
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="height: 400px; width: 1000px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine. Data is displayed on chart.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! Is it also working when you save the code in html file and open it in a browser? By me it works only in jsfiddle

Comment: Yes i tried by saving in html file and run it using local server.